# Why use range(len(n)-1)?

Tags: python

In a lot of the code I've done, in many instances `range(len(n)-1)` was used such as in the examples below:

To find a number that doubles in a list from another number:

```py
def double(n)
    for i in range(len(n)-1):
        if n[i]*2 == n[i+1]:
            print(n[i+1])
```

Takes a string and counts the number of times that two pairs in the string aren't
in correct order:

```py
def inversion(n)
    inv = 0
    for i in range(len(n)-1):
        for j in range(i+1,len(n)):
            if n[i]> n[j]:
                inv+=1
                break
```

This function takes a string n and returns true if there are 3 consecutive characters of the same value, and false otherwise:

```py
def triples(n):
    if n[i] == n[i+1] == n[i+2]: 
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I was wondering why do we always need to do `range(len(n)-1)` or `range(i+1,len(n))`, etc, couldn't we just used `range(len(n))` ? Understanding this would greatly help me in coding !

Comment: thats the number it will count up to

Comment: Why not count it to len(n) ?

Comment: Try it.  What are the observed effects?  Or, work it out on paper and determine *why* a given number is used.

Comment: When I have questions like this, I think about what actual numbers the range will have. That usually explains it.

Comment: @COCO2122 you can go `len(n)` depending on what you are doing (or really any time you want) presumably what you are trying to do doesnt work if you go to len(n)

Answer (score 1):

Take an example list:

```py
n = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

The length of this list, `len(n)` is `10`.

An example of a case that would require `len(n)-1` would be if you are running a process that looks at the adjacent (preceding or the next) element.

So for example, lets create a new list, `m`, that is the sum of the `n` and `n+1` elements.

So one could do this:

```py
m = []
for i in range(len(n)-1):
    m.append(n[i] + n[i+1])

print(m)
```

This prevents going out of range, since the (n+1) element would be out of bounds when `n` reached `10`. And remains in bound when at `n-1` which was 9.

In particular, in the above example, removing the `-1` would throw this error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So this is a use case.

You do not always need `range(len(n)-1)`. For example you could slice the list like this:

```
p = n[0:-1]
```

which given a shorter list:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

You can also use the `enumerate()` function to get adjacent (or other) elements of the list.

So, in summary, `len(n)-1` is **one of many** methods...  (depending on what is needed).